# Using Pandas, how to look up unknown values in column and create new column using function with unknown value as argument?

Tags: pandas, function, vlookup

I am learning to use Pandas to wrangle data from separate XLSX files, mostly with pd.merge and the loc method, and it works wonders. However I can't figure out how to apply the finishing touch ... I need to convert the foreign currency amounts in an "Interest" column to USD equivalents, using the FED data for the relevant Currency / USD pair. I need to do this for every last day of the quarter.

My dataframe with the local currency amounts to be converted looks as follows:

```
data =  pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Interest": [100, 200, 300, 400],
        "Currency": ['EUR', 'GBP', 'EUR', 'NOK'),
        "Date": ['31/03/2020', '31/03/2020', '30/06/2020', '30/09/2020']
    })
```

My dataframe with the currency pairs looks like this (but covers over 30 currency pairs for every quarter end in 2020):

```
fx = pd.DataFrame(
    {
         "Date": ['31/03/2020', '31/03/2020', '30/06/2020', '30/09/2020'],
         "Currency": ['EUR', 'GBP', 'EUR, 'NOK'],
         "Rate":     [0.80, 0.70, 0.82, 5]
    })
```

I believe a need a function that:

1st - For every 'Currency' item listed in Data, on every 'Date', retrieves the applicable rate from fx

2nd - Applies **that** rate to the Interest amount in Data, and create a new column.

My big issue is with 1. Many examples on stackoverflow suggest using NP WHERE, but I cannot figure out how to define the 'conditions' as I don't 'know' which currencies will be in Data?

In Excel, I would just have done a vlookup for the currency in Data, (combined with an IF to cater for the 4 different quarter end rates, depending on the Date field, and retrieved the rate in a new column. How to do this, any pointers in the right direction much appreciated.

Ari

Comment: Can you please edit your queston and put there expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to join the two dataframes based on the index `Currency` + `Date`:

```
data_fx = data.set_index(['Currency', 'Date']).join(fx.set_index(['Currency', 'Date']))

>>>
                         Interest  Rate
Currency    Date            
EUR         31/03/2020   100       0.80
GBP         31/03/2020   200       0.70
EUR         30/06/2020   300       0.82
NOK         30/09/2020   400       5.00
```

Then you just need to compute the column of interest:

```
data_fx['Interet_USD'] = data_fx['Interest'] * data_fx['Rate']
```

This assumes you only have 1 value of Interest per date and currency.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your response. Your solution is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I did not realize that it is possible to join dataframes on more than one key. Pandas is awesome. Thanks!